# In The MVP architecture does the Activity or Fragment must be the View component?

Tags: android, android-mvp

In our team, we separate the UI logic from the Activity or fragment by creating a new class for the view and let the Activity/Fragment manage the Life Cycle only is this good practice or not?

```
public abstract class BaseView implements ViewInterface {

protected View rootView;

protected Context contextInterface;

private TextView nameTextView;

public BaseView(Context  contextInterface, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    this.contextInterface = contextInterface;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);
    nameTextView=rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
}}
```

we decided to that based on this article: https://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/

Comment: But how can you make UI logic separate from Activity, Activity is itself a UI component. in MVP the V-part is the activity itself...

Comment: please read the article  https://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/

Comment: Design Patterns are not meant to be decided by a single article, you should do a research and see what is MVP and why did it came into existence, surely you may find community saying that android apps should be developed using MVP, but then why didn't android developers made the android framework keeping MVP into consideration, sometimes articles try to infest there understanding into the readers although that might prove wrong for the specified system you should see if the particular implementation of design patter suites to your requirement or not.

Comment: you can watch the videos at https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS4dsIMOKXAfPlgCTt4QOvQ to find out how you can use MVP in real coding. Hope this helps